# Powershell for Creating a scheduled task in which runs monthly

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a scheduled task with powershell, the task is supposed to run the 1st of every month, but I can't figure out how to use New-ScheduledTaskTrigger with a monthly interval.
EG:

```
$jobName = "Backup_EMR_Data"  
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $actionName -Argument  $arg -WorkingDirectory $SSISPackagePath  
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12:30AM   
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet  
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings  

Register-ScheduledTask $jobName -InputObject $task -TaskPath $taskPath -User $userName -Password $password
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I can't figure out how to use New-ScheduledTaskTrigger with a monthly interval.

> ```
> $triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
> $trigger = $triggers.Create(1) # Creates a "One time" trigger
> ```
>
> Now if we wanted to run the Task more than just once, let’s say on a monthly basis, we have to change and add a bit of code  The code above
>   uses Create(1) which means that the trigger is set to run once.
>
> ```
> $trigger = $triggers.Create(1) # Creates a "One time" trigger
> ```
>
> If we want to use another schedule we must use one of the following
>   values as explained in more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383915(v=vs.85).aspx).
>
> ```
> TASK_TRIGGER_EVENT                   0
> TASK_TRIGGER_TIME                    1
> TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY                   2
> TASK_TRIGGER_WEEKLY                  3
> TASK_TRIGGER_MONTHLY                 4
> TASK_TRIGGER_MONTHLYDOW              5
> TASK_TRIGGER_IDLE                    6
> TASK_TRIGGER_REGISTRATION            7
> TASK_TRIGGER_BOOT                    8
> TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON                   9
> TASK_TRIGGER_SESSION_STATE_CHANGE   11
> ```
>
> So let’s suppose we want to run the task the first day of every
>   month, we then have to change the code as following.
>
> ```
> $trigger = $triggers.Create(4)
> $trigger.DaysOfMonth = 1
> ```

Source [PowerShell – Creating Scheduled Tasks with PowerShell version 3](http://www.verboon.info/2013/12/powershell-creating-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell-version-3/)

Comment: Does this still work with PSv4, which is what the questioner seems to be using? According to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/18eb3f7e-ea54-4f60-8c0b-8659cad5e2d9/creating-a-scheduled-task-using-powershell-v4) it can't be done directly, and an XML solution is proposed.

Comment: @AFH I don't know. Lets wait for the OP to respond.

Comment: PSv3 I don't have any Scheduled Task cmdlets.  Schedule Job cmdlets use triggers, and I found the enum values usable for those triggers:  `PS > [enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.TriggerFrequency])` results in `None`, `Once`, `Daily`, `Weekly`, `AtLogon`, `AtStartup`.  This does not necessarily mean `Monthly` is not available to his version/module, but a similar exercise would answer the question.